# How to ensure my iPhone doesn't contact iCloud? (XR, iOS 16.2)

Tags: icloud

My iPhone was logged into iCloud today and I don't recall doing anything to request this. Is there a setting to ensure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: If you're logged into iTunes Store but don't want iCloud, in most cases it's better to log into iCloud and disable all the services you don't want. This way, you get the benefit of being in Apple-intended state ("iCloud enabled") and apps can use it to store data (many will expect this to be possible), without using Apple services you don't want.

This all being said, iCloud doesn't magically log itself in so perhaps an update changed how things are being displayed but it didn't change your login state unless you logged in yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't want either iTunes or iCloud. From what people are saying, I think I must have done something by accident to log in.

Comment: Can you explain what leads you to believe that your phone logged into iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Logging into iCloud is not automatic, it requires user intervention.

You can prevent user intervention from logging into iCloud using a configuration profile, if your device is supervised.

Set the following key-value in a configuration profile. You can use the following snippet in an existing profile, or create a new profile in Apple Configurator.

```xml
<key>allowAccountModification</key>
<false/>
```

[image: Allow modifying account settings in Restrictions]

Comment: Specifically, you cannot log into iCloud without providing your username and password